# Google Analytics Event Tracking on Links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

I've set up Google Analytics on my site, now there are some external links that I have to track.

According to the [official Google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#events), you just have to add a onclick EventListener on your element. Like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'EventCategoryName', 'EventName');">click me</a>
```

But it does not seem to work on my site. I disabled all ad-blockers, etc.
If I check the network tab in my developer tools, there is no request once I click the link. I'm working with the latest google analytics.js

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Did you read [Track outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en)?

Comment: not yet. but thanks for the tipp. I'll try if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that I was using the `gtag.js`version of Google Analytics, with the following tracking code:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
</script>
```

As described in the [gtag.js documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events). You should use the following snippet to track a event:

```
gtag('event', 'login');
```

Unfortunately it didn't work.

My temporary **solution**:
I went back to the analytics.js version, using the following snippet:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Now I'm able to successfully track if a user clicks an external link (or what ever action I want to track):

```
ga('send', 'event', 'EventCategoryName', 'EventName');
```